# Dynamic column name in where clause. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4

I want to dynamically place column name in my select-query. How I can do this?

```
public IEnumerable MyTable MySelect(string colName, string param)
{
  using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities ())
  {
     var query = from res in db.MyTable
     where res.colName.Contains(param)
     select res;
     return query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `res.Field<string>(colName)`?

```
public IEnumerable MySelect(string colName, string param)
{
  using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities ())
  {
     var query = from res in db.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
     where res.Field<string>(colName).Contains(param)
     select res;
     return query;
  }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910.aspx) is an example.

PS: I haven't compiled the code so might give error.

Comment: It's about _Generic Field and SetField Methods (LINQ to DataSet)_, but i use linq to entity and have compilator error in "res.Field<string>(colName)" that "MyTable does not contain a definition for Field and no extension method Field accepting a first argument of type DAL.MyTable could be found".

Comment: I have edited the answer so if you can give it a try now? I have replaced `db.MyTable` with `db.MyTable.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Unfortunately the same error:'DAL.MyTable' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first argument of type 'DAL.MyTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you make sure you have reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll?

Comment: I have to use linq to entity.

Comment: This brings data to app server and performs filter there. Not good, must filter on SQL side.

Answer (score 2):

Using dynamic linq:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

public IEnumerable MyTable MySelect(string colName, string param)
{
  using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities ())
  {
     var query = db.MyTable.Where($"{colName} LIKE %{param}%");
     return query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Dynamic Linq library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx) and ScottGu's [how to library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) here - it allows for dynamic filtering, sorting etc.

Answer (score 0):

use `Expression(Of Func(Of TableName, Boolean))` as input parameter to your method

```
    Public Function SelectFirstOrDefault(ByVal filterExpr As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As T 
    Return _dbContext.Set(Of T).FirstOrDefault(filterExpr)
End Function
```

then you can call it as below:

```
    Public Function Select() As MyTypeInfo
    dim expr = New Expression(Of Func(Of TableNameClass, Object))() {Function(x) x.Code, Function(x) x.LastModifiedDate, Function(x) x.Title}
    SelectFirstOrDefault(expr)
End Function
```