# Trying to get distinct values using LINQ with database field as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to select distinct values from MsSQL database using Linq queries
and passing the database field as a criteria, but it's giving me errors.

If a table has the following data:

```
Name | Age | Class | school
----------------------------
Anna,     23, grade 2, Havard
Kendricks,34, grade 2, Havard
Vikander, 27, grade 3, Covenant
Hathaway, 18, grade1,  Covenant
Gemma,    23, grade 4, Bowen
Jolie,    23, grade 5, Havard
Arteton,  24, grade 1, Bayero
Ana Armas 30, grade 2, Coventry
```

Now, from the table above I'm trying to retrieve the data by passing either the " school " or the " class " or even more fields and then return the distinct values based on these fields. How do I go about it?

```
// filterParam - is the field(class, school)
// then how do I select the distinct values...
```

Below is my code:

```
  public IEnumerable<ScbDataInfo> GetScbOptionsByFilter(string filterParam) {
            using (SRSContext entityContext = new SRSContext()) {

                var query = (from e in entityContext.Set<ScbDataInfo>()

                             where e[filterParam] == searchParam   //i passed it here
                             orderby e.RefNo, e.datepmt                             
                             select e).Distinct();

                return query.ToArray();

            }
        }
```

Comment: That is not supported. You need to either build your own predicate builder *or* you can incorporate a NuGet package like [DynamicQueryable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicQueryable/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic column name in where clause. Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421916/dynamic-column-name-in-where-clause-entity-framework)

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code, I throw together sometime ago from [DataTables.Queryable](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/DataTables.Queryable) by [Alexander Krutov](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov) licensed [MIT](https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/DataTables.Queryable/blob/master/LICENSE):

This works via Expressions and has no need to materialize your data, before you call `ToArray` by your self:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates predicate expression like 
/// <code>(T t) => t.SomeProperty.Contains("Constant")</code> 
/// where "SomeProperty" name is defined by <paramref name="stringConstant"/> parameter, and "Constant" is the <paramref name="stringConstant"/>.
/// If property has non-string type, it is converted to string with <see cref="object.ToString()"/> method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Data type</typeparam>
/// <param name="propertyName">Property name</param>
/// <param name="stringConstant">String constant to construnt the <see cref="string.Contains(string)"/> expression.</param>
/// <param name="caseInsensitive">Case insenstive Contains Predicate?</param>
/// <returns>Predicate instance</returns>
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringContainsPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string stringConstant, bool caseInsensitive)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(type, "e");
    var propertyExp = BuildPropertyExpression(parameterExp, propertyName);

    Expression exp = propertyExp;

    // if the property value type is not string, it needs to be casted at first
    if (propertyExp.Type != typeof(string))
    {
        // If we have an Enum, the underlying Entity Framework Provider can not translate the Enum to SQL.
        // Therefore we converting it first to the underlying primitive type (byte, int16, int32, int64 etc)
        //Todo: Sideeffects beobachten
        //Todo: Evtl möglichkeit finden Display Attribute zu implementieren um eine String Suche zu ermöglichen?
        //Todo: Notwendigkeit in NET Core 2.1 überprüfen
        if (propertyExp.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            exp = Expression.Convert(exp, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(propertyExp.Type));
        }

        exp = Expression.Call(exp, ObjectToString);
    }

    // call ToLower if case insensitive search
    if (caseInsensitive)
    {
        exp = Expression.Call(exp, StringToLower);
        stringConstant = stringConstant.ToLower();
    }
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(stringConstant, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(exp, StringContains, someValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
}

/// <summary>
/// Builds the property expression from the full property name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param">Parameter expression, like <code>e =></code></param>
/// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property</param>
/// <returns>MemberExpression instance</returns>
private static MemberExpression BuildPropertyExpression(ParameterExpression param, string propertyName)
{
    var parts = propertyName.Split('.');
    Expression body = param;
    foreach (var member in parts)
    {
        body = Expression.Property(body, member);
    }
    return (MemberExpression)body;
}

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="object.ToString()"/> method info. 
/// Used for building search predicates when the searchable property has non-string type.
/// </summary>
private static readonly MethodInfo ObjectToString = typeof(object).GetMethod(nameof(ToString));


/// <summary>
/// <see cref="string.ToLower()"/> method info. 
/// Used for conversion of string values to lower case.
/// </summary>
private static readonly MethodInfo StringToLower = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.ToLower), new Type[] { });

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="string.Contains(string)"/> method info. 
/// Used for building default search predicates.
/// </summary>
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContains = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) });
```

This creates a Filter Expression, where `propertyName` is the column, `stringConstant` the search value, and the bool, if the search should be case sensitive or not. `T` is the type of your `IQueryable<T>`.

With a [`PredicateBuilder`](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) you can do something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterColumns(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<string> columns, string searchValue)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null;
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        var expr = BuildStringContainsPredicate<T>(column,
                       searchValue, false);
        predicate = predicate == null ? PredicateBuilder.Create(expr) : predicate.Or(expr);
    }
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

This provides an extension method, hence the containing class must be static.

Now you can do the following:

```
entityContext.ScbDataInfos
    .FilterColumns(columnNames, searchValue)
    .OrderBy(e => e.RefNo)
    .ThenBy(e => e.datepm)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd like it implementation with Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Here I show a posible solution, with comments on code it explains how it works.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Filter ScbDataInfo with de field and value indicated
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterParam">Field name</param>
    /// <param name="searchParam">Value used in filter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<ScbDataInfo> GetScbOptionsByFilter(string filterParam, string searchParam)
    {
        // Here get property using reflection 
        var typeScbDataInfo = typeof(ScbDataInfo);
        var property = typeScbDataInfo.GetProperty(filterParam);

        //var filterExpression =
        using (var context = new SRSContext())
        {
            var query = context.ScbDataInfo
                .ToArray() // It force linq to sql to obtain all records from database. A poor implementation
                .Where(
                    m => property.GetValue(m) // Get entity with reflection
                            .ToString() // Convert to string because searchParam is string. It could be changed for the correct type or using dynamic type
                            .Equals(searchParam) // Simple equals for filter
                );
            return query.ToArray(); // Return array. Poor implementation
        }
    }
```

Example how it can be tested

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filter NAME:");
        var filterName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Filter VALUE:");
        var filterValue = Console.ReadLine();

        var program = new Program();
        var results = program.GetScbOptionsByFilter(filterName, filterValue);

        Console.WriteLine($"Total results: {results.Count()}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

PS: It has a poor implementation because used ToArray() so it obtain all records and after that the Where is done.

I thing so maybe a better implementation can be achive using Expression Tree.

Anyway with a few thousand records with a ordinary pc its work fine.